# Как задать плавный переход от одного изображения к другому при наведении курсора

Tags: css, webpack

Подскажите, как добавить плавности при смене изображения? При наведении курсора картинка меняется очень резко, а нужно, чтобы она плавно растворялась

```css
.image {
  background-image: url(path/to/image);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.image:hover {
  background-image: url(path/to/image);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="image"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавь транзишн.

```
.image {
  transition: 1s;
..... 
}
```